# Redirect .htaccess to ssl is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I'm trying to redirect xyz.com to https://xyz.com

My code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://xyz.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?sitemap.xml wp-content/sitemap.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

and also i try the following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

it shows this error 
**The page isn't redirecting properly**

actually it's a **WordPress** site.

how to solve that problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Have your rule as this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://xyz.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Also make sure in your WP permalink settings you have `home` and `site` URL reflecting `https://xyz.com/`

Comment: How do you think somebody can work on `It's not working` type of comments :) Provide details. What URL did you enter? Is this very first rule in WP .htaccess? Have you changed **WP permalink settings**?

Comment: xyz.com/sample-post/ its my wp permalink

Comment: There were more questions in my previous comment.

Comment: see my updated question. Not secure to post my website url here.

Comment: I didn't ask your actual domain. But you still didn't answer my other questions. My suggested rule must be right below `RewriteBase` and you **must change WP permalink settings**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62565/discussion-between-boopathi-rajan-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 1):

Please add the below code to your `.htaccess` file to redirect whole site to https.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

If you want to redirect selected pages, then rewrite rule as below.

```
RewriteRule ^page1(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/page1$1 [R,L]
```

If you prefer plugin, you can use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/https-redirection/.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it's working for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.xyz.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

please add this code in to your .htaccess file and let me know things.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

this code work fine in my site also please check you have SSL certificate in your hosting provider.

check this link http://kuldipmakdiya.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/redirect-htaccess-to-ssl-is-not-working/

Comment: its working on all my other sites. but it does not working in network site. i thing its my WordPress setting problem.